# Select Top 20 Percent Software Installed - Query Result shows software that dont belong to top 20 percent

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am hoping to create a report using Report Builder 3.0 that will show the Top 20 percent of software installed on the company PC's where those PC's have SCCM Client installed. I used the Select top 20 percent query below but the result shows software that has a count of 1.

Note that there are around 15,000 PC's i may be wrong on this but i would expect that those software with 1 count should not be included on the report?

Appreciate if anyone could guide me please as I may have used the wrong syntax?

Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT TOP 20 percent 
    s.DisplayName0, s.Publisher0
FROM 
    v_Installed_Software_Categorized as s
```

Comment: Using a `TOP` **without** a corresponding `ORDER BY` is pointless - you want the TOP 20 percent ..... **ordered by WHAT?!?!?**

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 20 PERCENT 
       DisplayName0, Publisher0, COUNT(*)
FROM v_Installed_Software_Categorized
GROUP BY DisplayName0, Publisher0
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: Hi Giorgi, i forgot to mention that i am a newbie to reporting...i tried your suggestion and it works. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: Hi Giorgi, i have a follow up question. On the output of the Top 20% there are software that has several versions for example BMC Remedy 7.5, BMC Remedy 7.6, Winzip 9, Winzip 10, etc...Is there a way to categorize those software with different version into one for example BMC Remedy, Winzip? and still have the total count of the software?